# WooCommerce checkout stuck on loading

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

On my checkout page woocommerce uses update_order_review to validate the checkout. But for some reason the response of this AJAX call does not only return a JSON string. It also returns everything that is in my functions.php in my theme.

I have no idea why it returns all this code. At the end of this it also return the right JSON string.

[image]

Comment: Remove all commented code from your function and make sure your are not print anything.

Comment: So it was indeed some of the html that always got printed, thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that the functions.php printed some html outside the functions.
I have made a check so that if wc-ajax isset, it wil not print any html.